# GXT3 - Change grid cell background color dependent on value (without CSS classes)

Tags: css, gxt

In GXT2 it was possible to change a cell's background color within the `GridCellRenderer`'s render method. With GXT3 this is not possible anymore and the [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8842821/2756574) approach is to use a `GridViewConfig` and override the `getColStyle` method.

My problem with this appoach is that I don't want to use css classes here but directly manipulate the cell's style as the desired background colors are only known at runtime.

My first idea was to do something like `grid.getView().getCell(rowIndex, colIndex).getStyle().setBackgroundColor(...)` within `getColStyle` but the returned cell always seems to be `null` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by myself:

I had to override `com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.GridView#doRender` and append some custom `SafeStyles` to the cell dependend on the `model`. To make it more flexible, I introduced also an inheritance of the `GridViewConfig` to do this job.

I hoped that there would be a simpler solution but at least it is one.